# How can you improve accessibility in Visual Studio for visually impaired people?

Tags: windows-xp, software-rec, visual-studio, accessibility

My friend has a with a visual impairment. He is interested in learning and programming in VB.NET.

He's currently using Narrator in Windows for his regular activities when using his computer. But is there any tool better than Narrator, which can assist him in programming in Visual Studio?

for e.g consider the  following code:

```
for i=0 to 10 
msgbox"hi";
end sub.
```

In the above piece of code there was an error and the narrator cant able to demonstrate there's an error in this line1 ,as normal people we can simple see the debugger and correct it,as he is visually impaired and the narrator fails to read the debugger error,

so i seek the help from this community is it there any tool to help him better than narrator?

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. According to the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq#dontask), questions should be reasonably scoped. This will get you more precise answers and makes it easier for others to find the topics later on.

Comment: @oliver salzburg sir i have clearly clarified that i need freeware tool which will help him in programming may i know why its closed?

Comment: like @MichaelHampton said, stick to one question .You're asking for a list of accessibility tools for OS X & Linux. and programming in VS using an accessibility tool. Also please explain what do you mean by "better than Narrator". Without using Narrator it's not possible to explain how x is better than y. Also look at [How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5372)

Comment: @sathya please review my question now

Comment: @vikki why don't you mention **what** the problem is? "when he places debugger on certain line", "when he tries to type certain syntax" ok **what** is the problem with that? We can't read your mind, neither are we sitting next to your friend to realize what the problem is. [edit] and mention *what* the problem is and what are you expecting the new program to do

Comment: @Sathya please review my question and thanks for the opportunity to edit the question

Comment: @vikki - I suggest upgrading to Windows 7 it has additional tools for visual imaired people.

Comment: @Ramhound i ll soon try and update then post sir and one more thing what can i prefer ultimate/professional/home edition?as you failed to mention it and i notice that you mentioned windows7 and please help me to choose which/what windows 7?(imaired correct it to impaired)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at the things listed on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4b5z3y3(v=vs.110)) page. While it does not appear that there is one setting for making visual studio easier to use for the visually impaired, and Narrator will not do very much, there are a variety of things that you can to make things bigger, etc.

You might also want to take a look at the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118984/how-can-you-program-if-youre-blind) question for a different type of solution (though something like [Jaws](http://www.freedomscientific.com/products/fs/jaws-product-page.asp) may either be something that you have already or way out of your price range).

Comment: i try and reply you

Comment: thanks for the great help it works fine and my friend and me thankufll to you thanks for the software,and one request sir you can post the link pages in detailed manner so it can be helpfull

Comment: @vikki there are three links. Which one did you find most useful?

Comment: personally i feel that first link cant be implemented since it helps only for low visioned people,2nd link describes the personal experience of true people,and third link about jaws, i felt that the 2nd link can be viewed as guidance and 3rd link can be an recommendation

Comment: @jaws work for fine at visual studio another question for you i ask here since i am barred form asking questions any other tools to say that particular video is loading,and how can a blind people browse internet particularly the sites which contain rich flash & video content?